# an anchor tag in a div should wrap the div

Tags: html, css

I want to wrap an inner `a-tag` in a `div`

I thought this works with a `display:block`.

However, it does not work.

Here is my code (https://jsfiddle.net/x6hw0e3u/):

HTML:

```
<div class="column dmd-card-box">
  <div class="media image-top medium">
    <div class="media-body text-center">
      <div class="excerpt">
        <p><span class="fa fa-user-plus fa-4x"></span></p>
        <p><strong>Treffsicher Neukunden gewinnen</strong></p>
        <p>Stellen Sie ihre Produkte genau den Kunden vor, die sich dafür interessieren.</p>        </div>
    <a href="" class="button ">Neukunden gewinnen</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dmd-card-box{
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid black;
  width:25%;
}
.button{
  display:block;
}
```

What I want to reach is:

- hide the string in the a-tag
- wrap the a-tag that I can click everywhere to open the link

Is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes. With position absolute. But why would you want to do it this way? Why don't you put all your content inside the a tag?

Comment: You need to wrap the html with the `<a>` tag. Example: `<a href="...."><div><span></span></div></a>`. Since HTML5 this is correct

Comment: Thanks guys. I can't edit the HTML markup thats why I ask this question.

Comment: You should put that in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Updated

As you can't change markup, do like this, using `position: absolute`

```css
.dmd-card-box {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 25%;
}
.media-body {
  position: relative;
}
.button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="column dmd-card-box">
  <div class="media image-top medium">
    <div class="media-body text-center">
      <div class="excerpt">
        <p><span class="fa fa-user-plus fa-4x"></span>
        </p>
        <p><strong>Treffsicher Neukunden gewinnen</strong>
        </p>
        <p>Stellen Sie ihre Produkte genau den Kunden vor, die sich dafür interessieren.</p>
      </div>
      <a href="" class="button ">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For everyone who can change markup, do like this, where you put the `div` inside the `a` (as of HTML5 this is now valid)

```css
.dmd-card-box {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 25%;
}

.button {
}
```

```html
<div class="column dmd-card-box">
  <div class="media image-top medium">
    <div class="media-body text-center">
      <a href="" class="button ">
        <div class="excerpt">
          <p><span class="fa fa-user-plus fa-4x"></span></p>
          <p><strong>Treffsicher Neukunden gewinnen</strong></p>
          <p>Stellen Sie ihre Produkte genau den Kunden vor, die sich dafür interessieren.</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest and recommended way to achieve what you want is to wrap the div inside the `a` tag:

```
<a href="" class="button ">
<div class="column dmd-card-box">
  <div class="media image-top medium">
    <div class="media-body text-center">
      <div class="excerpt">
        <p><span class="fa fa-user-plus fa-4x"></span></p>
        <p><strong>Treffsicher Neukunden gewinnen</strong></p>
        <p>Stellen Sie ihre Produkte genau den Kunden vor, die sich dafür interessieren.</p>        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
</a>
```

If there is any constraint in doing this, then you should set the `a` tag with absolute position and 100% width and height:

```
.dmd-card-box
{
 position: relative;
}
.dmd-card-box a
{
 height: 100%;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
```

You would also need to remove the text inside the `a` tag for this method. Here is updated JSFiddle after using absolute positioning for the link:
https://jsfiddle.net/x6hw0e3u/1/

```css
.dmd-card-box{
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid black;
  width:25%;
  position: relative;
}
.button{
  display:block;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="column dmd-card-box">
  <div class="media image-top medium">
    <div class="media-body text-center">
      <div class="excerpt">
        <p><span class="fa fa-user-plus fa-4x"></span></p>
        <p><strong>Treffsicher Neukunden gewinnen</strong></p>
        <p>Stellen Sie ihre Produkte genau den Kunden vor, die sich dafür interessieren.</p>        </div>
    <a href="" class="button "></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry. Can't update my html markup. I edit my question.

Comment: In that case, you can use the 2nd option I have mentioned. Here's a link to your updated JSFiddle, as per the 2nd option https://jsfiddle.net/x6hw0e3u/1/

Comment: No @Jay I have set parent's position as relative. That would set the reference boundary for its child elements and would not allow them to cover whole page. So in effect, a tag would be 100% of `.dmd-card-box` and start from left:0 and top: 0 of that div.